# pessimistic locking: Lock database entity grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, pessimistic-locking

I followed the grails documenation it says that to do pessimistic locking I can do like this:

```
def plan = Plan.findWhere(user:user, [lock: true])
```

so this locks the plan instance until save is finished on it.Now in my case I want to lock multiple plans at once,like this:

```
def plan = Plan.findAllWhere(user:user, [lock: true])
```

I am doing this in grails service which are transactional by default,but the above line is not working as expected.It doesn't lock all the rows and throws `stale state exception` if a concurrent transaction is performed.

How can I lock multiple rows when reading?

Please see a related question for more info : [concurrent transaction in grails resulting in database stale state exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890556/concurrent-transaction-in-grails-resulting-in-database-stale-state-exception)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this, which works for me:

```
Process.withNewTransaction {
    def process = Process.get(job.process.id)
    process.lock()
    process.sessionId = 0
    process.processId = 0
    process.save(flush:true)    
}
```

Comment: this works for you,because you only get one row by doing `Process.get(job.process.id)`.Please see the linked question that details why I can't use a solution like yours.Thanks